# Animating images in GWT

Tags: java, image, gwt

I wanted to know the best way of taking a list of images which come from an HTTP request, each image then needs to be retrieved.

I would then like to use the images to make an animation behaviour so it looks like the list of images is for example an animated gif. Moving between each image using a configurable time period.

This needs to be done using GWT. I saw that you can create a custom animation by using extends Animation and I also saw AbstractImagePrototype but I'm not sure what to use, also exists AnimationScheduler.

I made a simple example with javascript using setInterval but its not clear in GWT how this should be done.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi there! Stack Overflow is meant to help you solve the errors in _your_ code. But first we need to see _your_ code. You don't expect us to write the code for you, do you? Show us what you tried with `Animation` and maybe we can go from there.

Comment: Hi, no I don't expect you to write the code but some help in the most suitable direction to go would be useful hence the question before I start writing the code. Thanks.

Comment: `before I start writing the code` That's what I'm talking about! Go start writing the code. You saw something about using `Animation` didn't you? Don't be afraid and implement that; and when you run into errors, come back and update your question with some code to work with. Also, some of the "Related" questions in the right might be of help.

Comment: I tried with a simple Timer but the first time the transition is not so good as it takes a little to load the image.

Comment: That's a good start. Most places with a GIF work like that, in that they first show a static image (usually the first frame of the gif) and then the animation starts. Have you tried preloading the image _before_ you launch the Timer so it is already load when the first transition happens?